# Versioning for Worklight WAR files

Tags: version, ibm-mobilefirst, war

I do have a customer server code. means JAVA code and it was called from adapters. Whenever there is a change in JAVA code i need to take a build and need to deploy the war file to the server.Everything is okay and working fine. My problem is i can't identify which war file is deployed in Servers ( note we have lots of servers like TEST , PERF and PROD ). SO Is there a way to version a WAR file in worklight while building and i can see the version in the worklight console? or Suggest any other options to uniquely identify the WAR in server?

Am using Worklight 6.0 in Eclipse and all the servers.

Comment: Add version string into `MANIFEST.MF` file (I know nothing specifically about Worklight)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Worklight 6.0 this is not possible out-of-the-box.

Starting Worklight 6.1, you can see the version number of the deployed project's .war file by looking in Worklight Console > About > Additional Support Information.

What you could do, is manually add a text file to the generated .war file containing some identification number. Note that you should not add this into the .war file in Worklight Studio as the .war file is auto re-generated upon every change done in the project's server folder, so it must be added outside of Worklight Studio.